# PLPGSQL: Test if an element is found in an array literal

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.colors(color text)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $function$
DECLARE
    colorOptions text [];
BEGIN
    colorOptions := '{ red, orange, yellow }';
    IF color <> ANY (colorOptions) THEN
        raise notice 'This color is not accepted!';
    END IF;
END;
$function$;
```

The problem is that it raises a notice for any value I send it, irrespective of whether that value is in the array of colors or not.

For example, all of these raise a notice:

```
SELECT colors ('red');
SELECT colors ('black');
SELECT colors ('rubbish');
```

I tried using `IN` instead of `ANY`, as follows:

```
IF color NOT IN (colorOptions) THEN
```

That produces the following error:

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text <> text[]
LINE 1: color NOT IN (colorOptions)
```

Comment: Use `<> ALL (...)`

Answer (score 1):

> **expression operator ANY (array expression)**
> **expression operator SOME (array expression)**
> The right-hand side is a parenthesized expression,
> which must yield an array value. The left-hand expression is evaluated
> and compared to each element of the array using the given operator,
> which must yield a Boolean result. The result of ANY is “true” if any
> true result is obtained. The result is “false” if no true result is
> found (including the case where the array has zero elements).

Correct me if I am wrong.
I think `color <> ANY (colorOptions)` will always be true unless `color = colorOptions`.

Try `not (color = ANY (colorOptions))`